# how to change the default rails version in linux

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rbenv

I had all rails version gems install till 5.0.1
but when I do

```
rails -v
Rails 3.1.3
```

I want to update/change it rails version to 4.3.6. How can I achieve it.

Note: I had install ruby & rails using rbenv

Comment: I don't how  set to default rails version.But you can set rails version when creating a new rails application. The command is `rails _version_ new_application_name` Example `rails _4.3.6_ new_application_name`

Comment: I am unable to run server as project rails version is higher & current version is unable to find command rails server

Comment: Does it say `rails: command not found` when you run `rails s`? If it is may be you can run `gem install bundler`. BDW, what rbenv ruby version are you using?

Comment: it gives me help menu of the rails , ruby version is ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-linux] , rbenv version rbenv 0.4.0-210-gf0e8bdc

Comment: Are you in the root path of your app when you type `rails c` in your terminal?

Comment: yes, basicallly it identified rails but not rails server

Comment: Could you please try `gem update --system` then `gem install bundler`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127427/discussion-between-hard-developer-and-junan-chakma).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this

```
rbenv global 4.3.6
```

There is more info [here](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv)